# jQuery AJAX replaces submitted form with form (good), but it wont submit a second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, response, reload

Im using a loop in PHP to display the data for users in the admin section of a CMS.  Each row (user) includes a few icons that I want to connect to commands (ex: edit, delete, etc).  The last row of the table has empty input fields with a single icon (command) to allow new users to be added.  Here is the HTML for the users table...

```
<div id="wrap">
<form method="post" id="form_users">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="columns icons"></div>
            <div class="columns data">Username</div>
            <div class="columns data">First Name</div>
            <div class="columns data">Last Name</div>
            <div class="columns data">Email</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- .header -->
        <div class="row odd">
            <div class="columns icons">
                <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="0000000010" />
                <input type="image" src="../img/icons/delete_16.png" name="submit" value="delete" />
                <a href="?action=edit&userID=0000000010" class="edit"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">admin</div>
            <div class="columns data">david</div>
            <div class="columns data">kirkland</div>
            <div class="columns data">awesome@example.com</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row even">
            <div class="columns icons">
                <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="0000000001" />
                <input type="image" src="../img/icons/delete_16.png" name="submit" value="delete" />
                <a href="?action=edit&userID=0000000001" class="edit"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">coolguy</div>
            <div class="columns data">john</div>
            <div class="columns data">doe</div>
            <div class="columns data"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row new">
            <div class="columns icons">
                <input type="image" src="../img/icons/save_16.png" name="submit" value="new" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">
                <input type="text" name="user[2][username]" value="" maxlength="30" class="field new" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">
                <input type="text" name="user[2][first_name]" value="" maxlength="30" class="field new" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">
                <input type="text" name="user[2][last_name]" value="" maxlength="30" class="field new" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns data">
                <input type="text" name="user[2][email]" value="" maxlength="30" class="field new" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .table -->
</form>
```

When one of the icons is clicked I am using jQuery / AJAX to send the command to the server.  The response is the updated users table from `<form>` to `</form>`.  Here is the jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('input[name=submit]').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            // setup array
            var values = {};

            // which submit button was clicked
            var submit_type = $(this).val();

            if( submit_type=='new' ){

                $('form input:not(input[name=submit])').each(function(){
                    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                });

            }else{

                $(this).siblings().not('input[name=submit]').each(function(){
                    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                });

            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.users.php",
                data: { action: submit_type, data: values }
            }).done(function( response ) {
                $('#wrap').html(response);
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Everything works for the first action.  I can delete or add a user using the code above.  Clicking the icon sends the data to the AJAX.  The AJAX runs the appropriate query and I rebuild the user table.  That response comes back to the first file and users table is replaced with the new users table without a refresh.  Everything is good, until I try a second action.

The second click does nothing.  The third click causes the full page to reload and the action works again.  For example, I go to the page and click to delete a user.  They are deleted.  I click to delete another user.  Nothing happens.  I click again.  The page reloads and they are deleted.

Im not sure if it matters, but I use a PHP include the first time the page loads to include the same file my AJAX submits to.  This file generates the "user table".

```
<div id="wrap">
<?php include 'ajax.users.php'; ?>
</div>
```

I have searched all over and can't find anything pertaining to this situation exactly.  I cant seem to give google the right combo of keywords to get the answer I am looking for.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input[name=submit]').click(function(event){` only binds to the inputs that are there at the time `.click` is called.  Use event delegation.

```
$("#wrap").on('click', 'input[name=submit]', function (event) {
```

Comment: HOLY CRAP that was a fast answer... and it works.  Thank you so much!  I love stackoverflow and I really appreciate your help.  I spent far too long trying to fix this.  I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.  You answered so fast I cant even officially accept it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript attaches an event handler for the click event to any element that matches the "input[name=submit]" selector, but does this only once after the page has loaded.

This means that any other forms that would match the selector wont have this handler attached to them, for that you need a delegated event handler.

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=submit]",function() {...});
```

Ideally you should use a class to identify the submit buttons that should behave in this way, otherwise every submit button will use the same handler.